# Unbiased estimators - how to show unbiasedness?

Tags: variance, unbiased-estimator

Let $\hat{\theta}_i$ $(i = 1, 2)$ be two unbiased estimators of $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, which are uncorrelated, with $V(\hat{\theta}_i) = \sigma^2_i > 0$ $(i = 1, 2)$. 
For $\alpha \in [0, 1]$, define $\hat{\theta} = \hat{\theta}(\alpha) = \alpha\hat{\theta}_1 + (1 − \alpha)\hat{\theta}_2$.

What is the quickest way to find a value of $\alpha$ which minimizes $V[\hat{\theta}(\alpha)]$ and to show that we have an unbiased estimator?

Comment: All the techniques you need are exhibited in the closely related question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5392.

Comment: But how do you develop a clean proof of that?

Comment: One way uses Lagrange Multipliers, [as illustrated in a closely related situation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/9073/edit).  Another uses ordinary Calculus techniques--after all, $V(\hat\theta(\alpha))$ is a differentiable function of $\alpha$.  The most elementary method observes that $$V(\hat\theta(\alpha))=(\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)\left(\alpha - \frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}\right)^2 +\frac{\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2},$$ which has an obvious unique minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I always liked about this situation is its very illuminating intuition. We have, given unocorrelatedness,

$$\text{Var} [\hat \theta (\alpha))] = \alpha^2 \sigma^2_1 + (1-\alpha)^2 \sigma^2_2$$

Taking the derivative with respect to $\alpha$ and setting it equal to zero we have the condition

$$2\alpha\sigma^2_1 -2(1-\alpha) \sigma^2_2  = 0 \implies \alpha^* = \frac {\sigma^2_2}{\sigma^2_1 + \sigma^2_2}$$

while the second derivative is positive. So this is indeed a minimizer.

So the higher the variance of estimator No 2, the higher the weight given *to the other estimator*.

As regards unbiasedness, it comes immediately from the linearity property of the expected value, *irrespective* of whether we use the optimal $\alpha^*$ or not. Proving the linearity property in turn is proving the additive property in integration.